# iPhone 3/4 pixel perfection

Tags: iphone, css

I have a question, client needs a mobile website and it has to display pixel perfect on mobile devices (emphasis on iPhone).

I have a .PSD design which is 640px wide.

[This](http://www.iphoneresolution.com/) website tells me that older iPhones (<= 3) have width of 320px and newer ones (>= 4) have width of 640px.

My question is - how do I make a single page that will display the same on both the older and newer devices?
I know the newer versions have retina display, so do I leave the width and adjust everything to 640px or scale the .PSD down to 320px and adjust everything to that?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/features) comes in handy to generate your images at different scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a meta viewport tag so that the browser knows to calculate dimensions based on the device. Then define your css classes using percentages (not pixels).

An example looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

And a blog post: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html

If you need to load different images for different screen densities, you can try using window.devicePixelRatio to determine the screen density and then use javascript to load the correct image.

http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/06/devicepixelrati.html